# error: php.h no such file or directory

Tags: php, c++, apache

I am working with the following tutorial: http://abhinavsingh.com/blog/2008/12/php-extensions-how-and-why/

I did create in a folder the `php_sample.h` file. I have an error: `php.h no such file or directory.` I've installed `php and apache using apt-get install.` SHould i import in my file `php.h` ? I also don't know where to look for config.m4. I've searched in usr/lib/php5 but i didn't find it. In `usr/local` there is no appache folder. Need some tips. Thx! Appreciate

I would like to mention that i am working in ubuntu 10.10. I've tested a simple `.php code` after adding it in `/var/www` and it works.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you need php-dev package. php is just binary package while php-dev contains source files.

Comment: thx for reply. I've installed php-dev packadge. There is no config.m4 file in the build folder inside php5. why? How to resolve this?

Comment: as far as I know you should create your own config.m4 file and that "tells the UNIX build system what configure options your extension supports, what external libraries and includes you require, and what source files are to be compiled as part of it."
http://php.net/manual/en/internals2.buildsys.configunix.php

Comment: How can i install the php-dev package on Mojave ?

Answer (score 0):

Another possible cause for this error is trying to compile without PHP headers. And you may have different errors if you try to add headers by hand.

You can get them with the command `php-config --includes`:

```
gcc `php-config --includes` -c # ...
```

And this command is provided by the package php-dev.